# Data is not inserted into database of production site

Tags: php, mysql, linux, codeigniter

My data is not inserted into the database on the production site, while it is working correct on my local testing site. 
My configuration of codeigniter is correct. 
If I manually execute the query in the database, it shows the correct message and the data get's inserted into the database.*) When I print the query, it is as expected too.

I think it is a server configuration issue. I am using go daddy and mysql.

Database configuration:

```
$db['default']['hostname'] = 'localhost';
$db['default']['username'] = 'etc';
$db['default']['password'] = 'etc';
$db['default']['database'] = 'ieshopif_y';
$db['default']['dbdriver'] = 'mysql';
$db['default']['dbprefix'] = '';
$db['default']['pconnect'] = TRUE;
$db['default']['db_debug'] = FALSE;
$db['default']['cache_on'] = FALSE;
$db['default']['cachedir'] = '';
$db['default']['char_set'] = 'utf8';
$db['default']['dbcollat'] = 'utf8_general_ci';
$db['default']['swap_pre'] = '';
$db['default']['autoinit'] = TRUE;
$db['default']['stricton'] = FALSE;
```

*) After manually executing the query, I get this success message:

```
Connecting to database: ieshopif_y
Connected OK:file: /home/ieshopif/public_html/application/config/database.php Line: 82
```

I'd like to know how I have to configure the database to make it work, if it is a database issue.

Comment: where is the debug of the query? you posted the debug of the connection..

Comment: This question is in serious need of a rewrite; it's practically unintelligible with no capitalization or punctuation...

Comment: simply i need how to connect live db with domain.

Comment: This calls for basic debugging of the code that runs the query.

Comment: godaddy doesn't use localhost for databases, you'll have to check the hostname, username & password using in the control panel.

Answer (score 2):

These options could be different in production, development and testing:

```php
$db['default']['hostname'] = 'localhost';
$db['default']['username'] = 'etc';
$db['default']['password'] = 'etc';
$db['default']['database'] = 'ieshopif_y';
```

I suggest you separate this with an ENVIRONMENT constant defined on index.php, because the `hostname` could be different in production server. Try this:

```php
if (defined('ENVIRONMENT')) {
  switch (ENVIRONMENT) {
    case 'development':
      $db['default']['hostname'] = 'localhost';
      $db['default']['username'] = 'username';
      $db['default']['password'] = 'password';
      $db['default']['database'] = 'ieshopif_y';
      break;

    case 'testing':
    case 'production':
      $db['default']['hostname'] = 'domain.com';
      $db['default']['username'] = 'root';
      $db['default']['password'] = 'secure_pass';
      $db['default']['database'] = 'ieshopif_y';
      break;

    default:
      exit('The application environment is not set correctly.');
  }
}
```